# Laravel 5 entrust attachRolle

Tags: laravel, traits

I've cought mistake on laravel 5 and I can' solve it for a while. I'm using Zizaco/Entrust in Laravel 5 but i can't set trait for user model correctly. I'm running into error when I'm calling user model. This is my user model:

```
use Zizaco\Entrust\Traits\EntrustUserTrait; // I think it it's causing a problem.
use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;

class User extends Model {

use EntrustUserTrait; //or this

use Authenticatable, CanResetPassword;


protected $table = 'users';

protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password'];

protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];

}
```

And this is the line, which causes error:

```
$user->attachRole($owner);
```

As i understand my user model can't extend methods of trait.

Error: 
    Call to undefined method     Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::attachRole()

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't the User class extend Eloquent, rather than Model?

Comment: Isin't it a proper way since laravel 5? Been using it for a while.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. You clearly said Laravel 5 and yet I still read 4...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not the call to `attachRole()` itself but on what you are calling it. `$user` is not a model but a collection. You probably just have to switch out `get()` with `first()` in the query that fetches your user. Something like:

```
$user = User::where(...)->first();
$user->attachRole($owner);
```